# Sending and receiving messages between client and server program giving me unexpected result

Tags: c++, windows, winsock2

This is my server program code :

```
...
listen(s , 3);

//Accept and incoming connection
cout<<"\n\nWaiting for incoming connections... ";

int c = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

Socket newSocket = accept(s , (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c);
if (newSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    cout<<"\nAccept failed with error code : "<<WSAGetLastError();
}

// Since both server and client are now connected, it's time to send and receive players' name

string me;
char other[30];
fi.close(); fi.open("data.dat");
fi>>me; fi.close();

recv(newSocket,other,strlen(other),0);
send(newSocket,me.c_str(),me.length(),0);

cout<<me<<endl<<other;
```

This is client program code:

```
Socket s;
 //Connect to server
if (connect(s , (sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    cout<<"\nConnection error.";
    _getch();
    return 1;
}

//reading name and sending it to server
string me;
char other[30];
ifstream fi("cdata.dat");
fi>>me; fi.close();

send(s,me.c_str(),me.length(),0);
recv(s,other,strlen(other),0);

cout<<me<<endl<<other;
```

Suppose `data.dat` contains the word `Hero`
And `cdata.dat` contains the word 'Zero'

Now server side output is (ignoring other lines):

```
Hero
Zero%$#5^sdj
```

Client side output is (ignoring other lines):

```
Zero
He
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You can save all of these difficulties everybody has addressed below and many more by not using raw sockets.  ZeroMQ is a fantastic library that makes socket programming not only easy, but fun.  If you really don't want to be fighting your socket code until the end of time (because the problems that can crop up with sockets are countless), you'll definitely want to use a library to abstract out the socket work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the function `strlen` incorrectly here. This determines the length of a `c`-string by searching for the 1st occurrence of the character `\0` (the null terminator). Given that you do not initialise your `other` array, this value will be random, rather than 30 as you presumably expect.

You can change your code to explicitly state the number 30 as the maximum number of bytes to receive. You can also explicitly send the null terminator by adding 1 to your sent string length. So the server code becomes:

```
recv(newSocket,other,30,0);
send(newSocket,me.c_str(),me.length()+1,0);
```

And the client code becomes:

```
send(s,me.c_str(),me.length()+1,0);
recv(s,other,30,0);
```

Better still to change the hardcoded `30` to some integer constant, both in the `other` declaration and in the `recv` usage above.

Answer (score 0):

your 'other' array is of length 30, but you do not clip the length of that array by the return value of [recv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) which is the number of bytes that were read.

additionally strlen of the other array is dangerous because it's not a null terminated string but a constant size array, you should use the length of this array instead of strlen.

I believe if you do the same in client it will fix that as well. the other array could contain a random null byte when uninitialized which will give an odd strlen value you don't expect.